# Function that call n time another function with arguments

Tags: python, function, arguments, parameter-passing

why this code is printing once "potato" instead than 5 times ?

```
def print_word(word):
    print word
    return


def do_n(function , n):
    for i in range(n):
       function
    return

do_n( print_word("potato") , 5 )
```

Comment: Because you're not passing the function, or calling it inside `do_n`. You're calling it once and passing in the result (which is `None`).

Comment: Your function `do_n` doesn't not actually *call* the `function` argument. To call an object, you use `function()`, notice the parentheses. Just doing `function` evaluates to the function object, which doesn't get assigned to anything, and just gets discarded, and is essentially a useless line.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is actually not passing `print_word("potato")` ("the 'call' to the `print_word`") to `do_n`, but instead it's passing `None` since `print_word` returns `None`. Which means that the only time that `print_word` ran was at `do_n( print_word("potato") , 5 )`. What you can do instead is use `functools.partial`, which returns a function with the args applied to it:

```
from functools import partial

def print_word(word):
    print(word)
    return # side note: the "return" isn't necessary 


def do_n(function , n):
    for i in range(n):
       function() # call the function
    return

do_n( partial(print_word,"potato") , 5)
```

[functools.partial](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial):

> Return a new partial object which when called will behave like func
>   called with the positional arguments args and keyword arguments
>   keywords. If more arguments are supplied to the call, they are
>   appended to args.

Another way is to use a `lambda` statement or pass the argument separately:

```
def print_word(word):
    print(word)
    return # side note: the "return" isn't necessary 

def do_n(function , n):
    for i in range(n):
       function() # call the function
    return

do_n(lambda: print_word("potato"), 5) # use the lambda
```

Or:

```
def print_word(word):
    print(word)
    return # side note: the "return" isn't necessary 


def do_n(function , n, *args):
    for i in range(n):
       function(*args) # call the function
    return

do_n(print_word, 5, "potato") # pass the argument of print_word as a separate arg
```

Comment: Ah, the exact same solution. :-)

Answer (score 0):

To pass a function with arguments, you can either pass the arguments separately, or you can do a 'partial' application of the function, where you lock a number of variables. Here is such as solution to your problem, where I have 'partially' applied all variables. But, the function is still not *called* until the `function()` statement.

```
from functools import partial

def print_word(word):
    print word
    return

def do_n(function, n):
    for i in range(n):
        function()
    return

print_potato = partial(print_word, potato)

do_n(print_potato, 5)
```